# Failed to start hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

Failed to start hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked.

This happened after hostname update, tried to do a sudo service hostname start.

Comment: This looks like OS support, not a programming question.

Comment: Indeed my description was insufficient. I have a python backup script that looks for hostnames, in order to proceed with the backup, and was failing in finding one,(error in script), and because of that I have asked this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when there is a mismatch in hostname which causes the system to fail the lookup of the hostname.

Make sure these files are in-order and reflect proper entry for your new hostname

1. /etc/hostname
2. /etc/hosts

say your older hostname is: `hostname.old` and the new one is `hostname.new`

then `/etc/hostname` should be as following

```
hostname.new
```

and  `/etc/hosts` should contain an entry as follows:

```
...
127.0.0.1    hostname.new
...
```

Comment: Thank you anand , I have everything configured as you explained, my only mistake was to believe something is wrong(needed to run a python backup script, that looks for hostnames and was failing on finding the hostname.)

Answer (score 23):

Update the hostname in both `/etc/hostname` file and `/etc/hosts` file before running `service hostname restart`.

On newer systems running systemd (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04), have to use:

`sudo hostnamectl set-hostname new-host-name` . In here, edit `new-host-name` with your host name.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing to worry about. I've got the same problem when I tried to rename my computer name (hostname) in :

- `/etc/hostname`
- `/etc/hosts`

after editing both files, the command `sudo service hostname restart` returned the same error.

I simply rebooted my computer and the saw the computer name (hostname) has been successfully changed. **Just reboot your machine and you'll be fine.**

Comment: a simple logout and login worked fine on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

With latest Debian Stretch 9.6 you have to change /etc/hosts by yourself and also 
use hostnamectl. Here is a one-liner who does all stuff, original files are saved with date appended to the end. Maybe this works for other Distros

```
sudo -- bash -c 'echo "Please enter new Hostname"; old=$(hostname);read host; \
sed -i.$(date "+%H%M%S%d%m%y") -e "s:$old:$host:g" /etc/hostname;  \
sed -i.$(date "+%H%M%S%d%m%y") -e "s:$old:$host:g" /etc/hosts; \
hostnamectl set-hostname $host; echo "Old Name:$old and New Name is:$host"'
```

You should reboot after this to reflect all changes..